# Simple Configuration System

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

I have created a simple `ConfigManager` in C# that loads each line of a file. If the line contains `=` then it gets the before `=` (the key) and the after `=` (the value).

For example, my config file would look something like this:

```
# Comment here
MyConfigKey1=MyValue1
MyConfigKey2=MyValue2
MyConfigKey3=MyValue3
```

Obviously my config file wouldn't be that, but that's the layout of it. If the file is unreadable or is not found then the defaults are used.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace Sirius.Core.Config
{
    internal sealed class ConfigManager
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _configItems;

        public ConfigManager(string configFile)
        {
            _configItems = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            var logManager = Sirius.GetServer().GetLogManager();
            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(configFile) && Sirius.GetServer().GetUtility().IsFileLocked(new FileInfo(configFile)))
                {
                    _configItems = File.ReadLines(configFile)
                        .Where(IsConfigurationLine)
                        .Select(line => line.Split('='))
                        .ToDictionary(line => line[0], line => line[1]);

                }
                else
                {
                    _configItems.Add("database.host", "localhost");
                    _configItems.Add("database.username", "root");
                    _configItems.Add("database.password", "");
                    _configItems.Add("database.name", "database");
                    _configItems.Add("database.port", "3306");
                    _configItems.Add("database.max_connections", "10000");
                    _configItems.Add("sockets.port", "30000");
                    _configItems.Add("sockets.backlog", "50");

                    logManager.Warn("Using the default configuration.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                logManager.Error(exception.Message, exception);
            }
            finally
            {
                logManager.Information("Loaded Config Data [" + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms]");
                stopwatch.Stop();
            }
        }

        private static bool IsConfigurationLine(string line)
        {
            return !line.StartsWith("#") && line.Contains("=");
        }

        public string GetConfigElement(string key)
        {
            string value;

            if (!_configItems.TryGetValue(key, out value))
            {
                Sirius.GetServer().GetLogManager().Error("Missing configuration key `" + key + "`");
            }

            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That format looks very much like the old .INI format. Question: why not use the framework's own, much more robust, configuration system?

Answer (score 2):

The `ConfigManager` needs some clean-up because to my taste it's too tigthly coupled to the `Sirius` server and thus it's not testable.

First, make the constructor simpler. Constructors should not do any *heavy* job. Ideally the should only initialize fields or properties.

Move its logic into a new method like `LoadFromOrDefault` so that you know that it either loads the configuration from the specified file or gives you a default one that we move into a new `DefaultSettings` method.

The new `LoadFromOrDefault` not requries you to specify the file-name, a `Func` to determine whether the file is locked and a logger.

```
internal sealed class ConfigManager : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _settings;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public ConfigManager(IDictionary<string, string> settings, ILogger logger)
    {
        _settings = new Dictionary<string, string>(settings);
        _logger = logger;       
    }

    public static IDictionary<string, string> DefaultSettings() => new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "database.host", "localhost" },
        // ..
    };

    public static ConfigManager  LoadFlomOrDefault(string fileName, Func<string, bool> isLocked, ILogger logger)
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(fileName) && isLocked(fileName))
            {
                var settings = File.ReadLines(fileName)
                    .Where(IsConfigurationLine)
                    .Select(line => line.Split('='))
                    .ToDictionary(line => line[0], line => line[1]);
                return new ConfigManager(settings, logger);
            }
            else
            {
                logger.Warn("Using the default configuration.");
                return new ConfigManager(DefaultSettings(), logger);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            logger.Error(exception.Message, exception);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            logger.Information("Loaded Config Data [" + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms]");
            stopwatch.Stop();
        }
    }

    private static bool IsConfigurationLine(string line)
    {
        return !line.StartsWith("#") && line.Contains("=");
    }

    public string GetConfigElement(string key)
    {
        string value;

        if (!_settings.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            _logger.Error("Missing configuration key `" + key + "`");
        }

        return value;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _settings.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var config = ConfigManager.LoadFromOrDefault(
    "myconfig.ini", 
    fileName => Sirius.GetServer().GetUtility().IsFileLocked(new FileInfo(configFile)), 
    Sirius.GetServer().GetLogManager()
);
```

And agian, you can now test it without the `Sirius` server.

---

***Desclimer**: This is just a rough idea and not ready-to-use code so it might contain some small bugs or not entirely satisfy your needs yet.*

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in this method.

> ```
> private static bool IsConfigurationLine(string line)
> {
>     return !line.StartsWith("#") && line.Contains("=");
> }
> ```

The following input from a file will bring cause the check to return `true`, likely bringing the rest of the code to its knees.

> ```
> =SomeValue
> ```

It doesn't start with a comment and contains an equals sign, but isn't a valid configuration line.